# Exclude instance when updating Recursive Foreign Key in Django

Tags: django

I have the following model and modelform for an Employee:

**models.py**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    reports_to = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True, blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
```

The idea is that the boss of an Employee is themselves an Employee.

The problem is that, when I'm updating the instance, the respective form field created is a dropdown with all Employees, including the object I'm updating itself.

Is there an easy way to remove the instance itself from the dropdown options so that no employee has him/herself as their own boss?

PS.: I'm not looking for a solution that validates the form field after submitting a form, but rather removing the option from the form dropdown altogether. Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried? There's a few options here: override the form's `__init__` method to change the queryset of the `ModelChoiceField` could be one way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can modify the `queryset` of the respective field, and omit the instance, if that instance (already) exists. Like:

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = self.instance
        if instance.pk is not None:
            self.fields['reports_to'].queryset = Employee.objects.exclude(pk=instance.pk)

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
```

In case the instance *has* a `pk` that is not `None` (that means that you *edit* the instance, not create a new one), then we thus "patch" the queryset that contains all the `Employee`s, except for that one.